# add_editor_style() not working in 3.0.3

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to use `add_editor_style()` to add custom editor styles.

In `template.php` I've added:

```
<?php
add_editor_style();
```

I have a stylesheet in my theme directory called editor-style.css with the following css:

```
/* editor-style.css */
div { background-color: orange;}
p {color: red!important; font-size: 18px!important; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `add_editor_style()` must be in `functions.php` to work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to Drupal and was using template.php instead of functions.php.